# How make column monotonically decreasing if it is not?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which contains a column 'A' (numeric values), I am able to check whether the column is monotonically decreasing using 
   df['A'].is_monotonic_decreasing

```
df['A']

    5
    4
    3
    6
    2
```

I want to make the column as monotonically decreasing.

```
df['A']
   5
   4
   3
   3
   2
```

I am to do this using the brute force method

```
min = df['A'][0]
for index,value in df['A'].iteritems():
   if value <= min:
      min = value
   else:
      df['A'][index] = min
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.minimum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) on the column data -

```
In [204]: df
Out[204]: 
   A
0  5
1  4
2  3
3  6
4  2

In [207]: df['A'] = np.minimum.accumulate(df['A'])

In [208]: df
Out[208]: 
   A
0  5
1  4
2  3
3  3
4  2
```

Or use `out` param for in-place edit -

```
np.minimum.accumulate(df['A'],out=df['A'].to_numpy(copy=False))
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, Thanks